# Convert a double to a string containing rational and surd

Tags: c#, performance, .net, mathematics

First off, code:

```
string FracSurd(double value)
{
    //A C# 7 local function
    double GCD(double a, double b)
    {
        while (b > 0)
        {
            var rem = a % b;
            a = b;
            b = rem;
        }
        return a;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1e6; i++)
    {
        var SubjectToTest = value / Math.Sqrt(i);
        for (var denom = 1.0; denom <= 500; denom++)
        {
            var numer = Math.Round(SubjectToTest * denom);
            if (SubjectToTest - numer / denom == 0)
            {
                int Square = 1, a = i;
                for (int b = 2; a > 1; b++)
                    if (a % b == 0)
                    {
                        int x = 0;
                        while (a % b == 0)
                        {
                            a /= b;
                            x++;
                        }
                        //Console.WriteLine("{0} is a prime factor {1} times!", b, x);
                        for (int j = 2; j <= x; j += 2) Square *= b;
                    }
                var LCM = GCD(numer, denom);
                numer /= LCM;
                denom /= LCM;
                var Builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder(numer.ToString());
                Builder.Append(" / ").Append(denom).Append(" √");
                foreach (var Char in (i / Square).ToString())
                {
#if WINDOWS_UWP
                    Builder.Append("̅");
                    Builder.Append(Char);
#else
                    Builder.Append(Char);
                    Builder.Append("̅");
#endif
                }
                return Builder.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    throw new ArithmeticException("Cannot find appropiate fraction and surd.");
}
```

The code contains a lot of loops. How can I increase its performance so I can expand its range of input?

Comment: Is this real code? When did C# start supported nested functions?

Comment: Check out C# 7's local functions :) Btw it's released with VS2017 so you may not be able to compile it in older VSs.

Comment: @CodyGray not up-to-date? ;-) You can also run it with the latest LINQPad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a good question because the objective is unrealistic. The code (or perhaps the problem statement) is also flawed since √1 is considered a surd, which - if I am not mistaken - is wrong. (A surd is an "irrational nth root of a positive integer (n > 1)", i.e. it has a non-recurring floating point representation.)

**Here is why the objective needs sorting out**

Reasonably performant algorithms exist to express floating point numbers as irrational numbers (all of which may be expressed as x / y * √1).  Here's an example (E&OE):

```
static string Frac(double value)
{
  const double compareTolerance = 1.0E-12;
  bool isNegative = value < 0;
  value = Math.Abs(value);

  long numerator = 1L;
  long denominator = 1L;
  double fraction = (double)numerator / denominator;

  while (Math.Abs(fraction - value) > compareTolerance)
  {
    if (fraction < value)
      numerator++;
    else
    {
      denominator++;
      numerator = (long)(value * denominator);
    }
    fraction = (double)numerator / denominator;
  }
  return $"{numerator} / {denominator} ~= {fraction}, error = {value - fraction}";
}
```

Given `Console.WriteLine(Frac(2.0 / 3 * Math.Pow(7, 1.0/3)));`

One gets `1238109 / 970847 ~= 1.27528745518089, error = 7.04103442217274E-13`

Reducing the "tolerance" leads to finding bigger (numerator, denominator) pairs giving "increasingly accurate" rational equivalents (within the significant digit limit of the floating point type of course). Taking the floating point representation of any rational, multiplying (or dividing) by a (floating point approximation to a) surd, just gives another floating point number which can be (approximately) represented by a rational. Every floating point number therefore has virtually unlimited `rational * surd` representations, so you need to specify how you want to limit the search range and/or output possibilities.

Comment: I'd like the fractional part to be sim

Comment: ple as possible, so that the result can be read by humans easily

Answer (score 1):

My problem with the question remains so I leave my first answer unchanged and offer this second one to say *"thank you for the fun"*.

The following code is (1) not tidy, (2) not optimal, (3) is a guide based on constraints I made up.  It targets "a small denominator" for the irrational number and limits the surd to "nth roots of (roughly) 2..11 for n in [1(trivial),2,3,4,5]".

**Output** for this sample

```
0.0526315789473684 ~= 1 / 19, error = 0
19 ~= 19 / 1, error = 0
1.27528745518159 ~=  7 ^ (1 / 3) * 2 / 3, error = 0
180.220806218631 ~=  1 / 7 ^ (1 / 3) * 1379 / 4, error = 2.8421709430404E-14
3.73919839064901E-06 ~=  1 / 10 ^ (1 / 2) * 1 / 84571, error = -2.23732252003866E-13
6.35663726410332E-05 ~=  1 / 2 ^ (1 / 5) * 7 / 95866, error = -6.62044705623983E-13
```

*Notice how the last two outputs differ from their input expressions.  This is all approximate!*

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using ValueRootPair = System.Tuple<int, double>;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    // Store the best guess so far. Naming as follows: val ~= x^((rootUnder ? -1 : +1)/n) * num / denom
    class Solution
    {
      public bool rootUnder;
      public int n, x;
      public double val, num, denom;
    }

    const double compareTolerance = 1.0E-12;

    // Returns the <paramref name="numerator"/> and <paramref name="denominator"/> for a rational approximation of <paramref name="value"/>
    static void Frac(double value, out long numerator, out long denominator)
    {
      bool isNegative = value < 0;
      value = Math.Abs(value);

      numerator = 1L;
      denominator = 1L;
      double fraction = (double)numerator / denominator;

      while (Math.Abs(fraction - value) > compareTolerance)
      {
        if (fraction < value)
          numerator++;
        else
        {
          denominator++;
          numerator = (long)(value * denominator);
        }
        fraction = (double)numerator / denominator;
      }
    }

    // Generates series of <paramref name="qty"/> (value, root) tuples, for values >= 2 where root = value ^ <paramref name="degree"/>. Skips square roots of squares, cube roots of cubes etc.
    static IEnumerable<ValueRootPair> Roots(int degree, int qty = 10)
    {
      int v = 2, count = 0;
      while (count < qty)
      {
        var root = Math.Pow(v, 1.0 / degree);
        if (Math.Abs(Math.Round(root) - root) > compareTolerance)
        {
          count++;
          yield return new ValueRootPair(v, root);
        }
        v++;
      }
    }

    static string Test(double value)
    {
      var bestGuess = new Solution();
      long num, denom;
      double v = value;
      int degree = 1;
      var vrp = new ValueRootPair(1,1);

      void Update(bool surdUnderneath = false)
      {
        bestGuess.rootUnder = surdUnderneath;
        bestGuess.num = num;
        bestGuess.denom = denom;
        bestGuess.n = degree;
        bestGuess.x = vrp.Item1;
        bestGuess.val = v;
      }

      // Start by getting a rational approximtion without a surd factor...
      Frac(v, out num, out denom);
      Update();

      for (degree = 2; degree < 6; degree++) // roots of degree 2,3,4,5
      {
        foreach (var surd in Roots(degree)) // default to 10 of each
        {
          vrp = surd;
          v = value / vrp.Item2; // take out surd
          Frac(v, out num, out denom);
          if (denom < bestGuess.denom) Update(false); // Target small denominator
          if (denom < 100) goto breakout; // stop if 2 digit denominator has been found

          v = value * vrp.Item2; // take out 1/surd
          Frac(v, out num, out denom);
          if (denom < bestGuess.denom) Update(true);
          if (denom < 100) goto breakout; // stop if 2 digit denominator has been found
        }
      }
      breakout:
      var ret = $"{value} ~= ";
      if (bestGuess.x != 1)
        ret += $"{(bestGuess.rootUnder ? " 1 /" : "")} {bestGuess.x} ^ (1 / {bestGuess.n}) * ";
      ret += $"{bestGuess.num} / {bestGuess.denom}";
      ret += $", error = {value - bestGuess.num / bestGuess.denom * Math.Pow(bestGuess.x, (bestGuess.rootUnder ? -1.0 : 1.0) / bestGuess.n)}";
      return ret;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(Test(1.0 / 19));
      Console.WriteLine(Test(19.0));
      Console.WriteLine(Test(2.0 / 3 * Math.Pow(7, 1.0/3)));
      Console.WriteLine(Test(1379.0 / 4 / Math.Pow(7, 1.0/3)));
      Console.WriteLine(Test(1.0 / 267437));
      Console.WriteLine(Test(17.0 / 267437));
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

I don't have time to redo my entire original answer but here is something very useful performance-wise that I came across today...
**Vast Improvement on Frac()**

```
//  Ref: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Convert_decimal_number_to_rational 
public static double Frac2(double value, out long numerator, out long denominator, out int iterations, double tolerance = 1.0E-12, long maximumDenominator = 4096)
{
  /* a: continued fraction coefficients. */
  long a;
  var h = new long[3] { 0, 1, 0 };
  var k = new long[3] { 1, 0, 0 };
  long n = 1;
  bool neg = value < 0;

  if (maximumDenominator <= 1) maximumDenominator = 4096;

  double f = neg ? -value : value;

  // ReSharper disable once CompareOfFloatsByEqualityOperator
  while (f != Math.Floor(f)) { n <<= 1; f *= 2; }
  var d = (long)f;

  /* continued fraction and check denominator each step */
  for (iterations = 0; iterations < 64; iterations++)
  {
    a = n != 0 ? d / n : 0;
    if (iterations != 0 && a == 0) break;

    var x = d; 
    d = n; 
    n = x % n;

    x = a;
    if (k[1] * a + k[0] >= maximumDenominator)
    {
      x = (maximumDenominator - k[0]) / k[1];
      if (x * 2 >= a || k[1] >= maximumDenominator)
        iterations = 65;
      else
        break;
    }

    h[2] = x * h[1] + h[0]; h[0] = h[1]; h[1] = h[2];
    k[2] = x * k[1] + k[0]; k[0] = k[1]; k[1] = k[2];
  }
  numerator = neg ? -h[1] : h[1];
  denominator = k[1];
  return value - (double)numerator / denominator;
}
```

See comment for link to my source,
Results are typically obtained many orders of magnitude faster.

**Test code**

```
      foreach (double d in new double[] 
  { 
    0.9054054, 
    0.518518, 
    0.75, 
    0.4285714, 
    0.833333,
    0.90909, 
    3.14159265358979, 
    2.7182818284590451
  })
  {
    long num, denom;
    int it;
    var err = Frac(d, out num, out denom, out it, 1000000);
    Console.WriteLine($"{d,10} by Frac1(): {num,10} / {denom,-10} {err,25} in {it,10} iterations");
    err = Frac2(d, out num, out denom, out it, 1000000, /*d >= 2 ? 65536 : */4096);
    Console.WriteLine($"{d,10} by Frac2(): {num,10} / {denom,-10} {err,25} in {it,10} iterations");
  }
```

**Comparative results Frac1() vs Frac2()**

```
 0.9054054 by Frac1:         452704 / 500001 -7.89187621585974E-07 in 1000000 iterations
 0.9054054 by Frac2:             67 / 74     -5.40540534554879E-09 in       6 iterations
 0.518518 by Frac1:          259259 / 500000                     0 in  999997 iterations
 0.518518 by Frac2:              14 / 27     -5.18518518455302E-07 in       4 iterations
 0.75 by Frac1:                   3 / 4                          0 in       5 iterations
 0.75 by Frac2:                   3 / 4                          0 in       3 iterations
 0.4285714 by Frac1:         214287 / 500001 -1.74285371429272E-06 in 1000000 iterations
 0.4285714 by Frac2:              3 / 7      -2.85714285563898E-08 in       4 iterations
 0.833333 by Frac1:          416668 / 500001  -1.3333313333419E-06 in 1000000 iterations
 0.833333 by Frac2:               5 / 6      -3.33333333379926E-07 in       4 iterations
 0.90909 by Frac1:            90909 / 100000                     0 in  199997 iterations
 0.90909 by Frac2:               10 / 11     -9.09090909106958E-07 in       4 iterations
 3.14159265358979 by Frac1: 1570796 / 500000  6.53589789845199E-07 in 1000000 iterations
 3.14159265358979 by Frac2:     355 / 113    -2.66764192513591E-07 in       4 iterations
 2.71828182845905 by Frac1: 1084483 / 398959  4.81836792687318E-13 in  797917 iterations
 2.71828182845905 by Frac2:    2721 / 1001    1.10177326817507E-07 in      11 iterations
```

Comment: Nice try, but the inner code is still very similar to the original.

Comment: @Happypig375: See improvement to Frac().  It achieves 2 things: greatly improved performance (by using continued fractions, see link in code comment) and adds maxDenominator parameter that gives better control of fractional part "simplicity" (I interpret your requirement to imply that you consider fractions with large denominators to be less simple).